# Solving $\int_{0}^\infty{\sin(x^4)}dx$

Tags: integration

any hints on how to solve the following integral : $\int_{0}^\infty{\sin(x^4)}dx$

I understand that comparison test doen't work because the function keeps alternating the signs, i tried integration by parts but also didnt work

thanks !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
$$\int{\sin(x^4)}\,dx=\Im \int e^{ix^4}\,dx$$ Think about the gamma function.